# How to install "PC Companion" software of Sony Xperia?

Tags: software-installation, crossplatform

I've successfully installed "PC Companion" Sony Xperia in Windows. Has anyone been able to install pc companion sony xperia in within Ubuntu or any other Linux distro?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36376/cant-explore-files-on-my-sony-xperia-u-using-my-ubuntu-12-10-laptop

Comment: Use one of these instead for file transfer http://askubuntu.com/questions/189591/connecting-android-4ice-cream-sandwich-jelly-bean-kitkat-phone I've tried SSH SFTP and it just works (in addition to allowing you to run a shell when you need it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program is [specified for Windows only.](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/)

I searched but didn't find an alternate for Linux. So when a program simply does not exist for Linux, you cannot install it (at least with the native way).

You can use either Wine or VirtualBox and resolve your problem.

In case you just need to exchange files from pc to phone you can use ADB -> [ADB and Sony xperia](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1612273)

From [Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/)

- [How to install and use Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) --> [WineDB Sony Companion](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=12297)
- [How to install and use VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox)--> [Virtual Box and Sony Companion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1921893)

Comment: this is like a general answer adding few info about how to solve the issue ... most of program run bad on wine or need some particular istructions

Answer (score 3):

Others have been using a virtual machine for this, sadly there isn't any support for Ubuntu on PC Companion (i just tried).

WINE support seems limited and running it on this end seems incredibly glitchy, but if it's only for the storage purpose then you can change the settings on your phone to USB Storage mode if you want to get into the contents on your device.

Answer (score 1):

- Install virtualbox and extensionpack (for usb support) from their website
- In your user/group settings (ubuntu) add your linux username in group 'vboxusers' (for rights adding usb devices)
- Create windows session in vb
- Connect your device and add them in usb settings (virtualbox settings. or windows won't recognize it. Has to be done for every device u want to use)
- Connect in flashboot as well and add the usb device (turn phone on while holding volume up)
- Start windows session and install windows
- Download phonedriver and flashbootdriver from sony website and install in windows.
  -Install pc companion and you should be fine.

I advise to make a proper backup with pc companion before upgrade, because sometimes windows crashes..

Easiest way is to ask someone with a windows machine ;-)

I tested with a windows 7 copy from digital river (official), didn't enter a serial and didn't avtivate.. So 30 day trial..

Thank god most updates are handled on the phone itself.. But the upcoming new android version can only installed by the companion..

Pc companion is the only thing i need windows for, so this is fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

regarding installing PC Companion in Ubuntu (Linux)

Might be redundant, for sync and backup of phone contacts, calendar etcetera simply get a Google+ account and all these matters are solved. Works perfectly calendar functions simple aswell as more hardcore fex mailing a meeting to other participants that use Google+ and have Android phones, the reciepent answer and tells if they are taking part of it or not, if yes the booking appears in ther phone aswell :-)

For filebackup simply connect your Android smartphone (fex Experia S) via USB cable and all files appear in Ubuntu as a portable USB disc, just drag and drop.....
or, connect your Sony Xperia S to a USB portable disc using OTG (On the go) USB cable and move all files to that memory or harddrive :-) really simple.... Go Sony...

When in need of Android update of OS, well, depends on the carrier, Ive got Telia in Sweden and so far all updates have been via the phones internet connection. So choose your provider based on that.

Well, thats about it, think that most things are covered by that..

BR

Lars Lundblad