# infinite loop in terminal

Tags: command-line, android

I have tried to connect my Asus transformer 300T tablet (android 4.1 ) to Ubuntu 12.04 by following the steps in [this tutorial](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access).

However something went wrong in this step (I am not sure which exactly ):

> You’re almost done! Now, restart your computer, and then run these three commands :

```
echo “alias android-connect=\”mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\”" >> ~/.bashrc
echo “alias android-disconnect=\”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\”" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

and now my terminal is repeatedly showing non-stop (seems like an infinite loop)

```
alias: command not found
alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/TransformerT300T”
```

This happens even after I restarted my computer. Can anyone diagnose what is going wrong?

Here is a screenshoot:

[image]

Comment: Here are some alternative instructions, if you are willing to give them a try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216246/ubuntu-nexus-7-as-usb-device-does-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `.bashrc` file and edit those two lines you added. Remove the double quotes and add single quotes

```
alias android-connect='mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus'
alias android-disconnect='fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus'
```

After editing try to source the .bashrc file.

Comment: thank you very much ~! this works right away without even have to source the .bashrc .