# Mounting Nexus 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 through USB?

Tags: 12.04, mount, android, nexus-7, mtp

Please help me troubleshoot. I would like to transfer files between my Ubuntu 12.04 and Nexus 7 (Android 4.2) I have first followed this link [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216246/ubuntu-nexus-7-as-usb-device-does-not-work) carefully without success, rolled back all changed. The tried this other one simpler one [link](http://blog.jsntng.me/2012/08/mounting-nexus-7-on-ubuntu-1204.html).

Nevertheless, upon:

```
mount /mnt/nexus7
```

I get:

```
Listing raw device(s) Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4e41) is a Google Inc
(for Asus) Nexus 7 (mode 1).    

Found 1 device(s):    Google Inc (for
Asus): Nexus 7 (mode 1) (18d1:4e41) @ bus 1, dev 11 

Attempting to connect device Android device detected, assigning default bug flags

Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)
```

and even doing an `ls -l /mnt` generates:

```
ls: cannot access nexus7: Transport endpoint is not connected

total 4

d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? nexus7
```

Ideas why that is happening???