# Problems with mtp on Nexus 4 and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, mtp, nexus-4

I have had some sort of scripts installed (I think that they were something with go-mtpfs ) but I cannot get those running anymore after upgrade to 13.10.

Basically what happens now is when I plug in the Nexus in I get the following in `dmesg`

```
[ 1735.057817] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1739.696027] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1739.792273] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee1
[ 1739.792282] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1739.792288] usb 2-1.3: Product: Nexus 4
[ 1739.792293] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: LGE
[ 1739.792297] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have also tried this :

```
$ ll /media/ | grep nexus
drwxrwxrwx  2 user user     0 Jan  1  1970 nexus
$ sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/nexus
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee1) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/10 (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung): Nexus 4/10 (MTP) (18d1:4ee1) @ bus 2, dev 6
Attempting to connect device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
```

And after few seconds I would get

```
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
```

Having installed

```
go-mtpfs 0.1-1~20130108~webupd8~quantal
libmtp-common 1.1.6-2
libmtp-runtime 1.1.6-2
libmtp9:amd64 1.1.6-2
libnet-smtp-ssl-perl 1.01-3
mtp-tools 1.1.6-2
mtpfs 1.1-4.1
```

I can get the `nexus` mounted in nautilius but only with `Playlists` and `Internal storage` and if I press Internal storage I get new window with the same content (infinite loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer, [found here](https://askubuntu.com/a/216366/13247), discusses how to get MTP working.  I've learned, however (due to downvotes) that this answer is no longer valid.

I believe that, after 12.04, this is no longer required and Ubuntu should handle MTP natively without the help of other resource/library.

Maybe you should attempt to set this up without go-mtpfs, even though it *used* to be advised.