# Android Media sync LG Optimus L7 (P705) with ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: mount, android, automount, mtp

I can't connect my Android LG Optimus L7 (P705) with Ubuntu via media sync (MTP), just to see or transfer file / media inside my internal / external memory from computer to handphone vice versa, previously I used Windows XP and Windows 7, media sync no problem with both OS.

Please help regarding this issue. Thanks.

---

My phone is detected using `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 005 Device 027: ID 1004:631c LG Electronics, Inc.
```

but unfortunately, my phone still not detected when I open home folder.

I am still looking for solution regarding this MTP issue on my LG optimus L7 since my music player (Philips Go Gear) works on MTP also and did not detected by Ubuntu but detected even on Windows XP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: ["Connecting Android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich / Jelly Bean) phone to Ubuntu 12.04"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189591/connecting-android-4ice-cream-sandwich-jelly-bean-phone-to-ubuntu-12-04/247046#247046).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

MTP doesn't work out of the box on linux. Inorder to transfer files to your phone's external_card you will have to change the usb connection mode on your phone to MSC(Mass Storage Mode).

If you want to access your phone storage and external_card on Linux then all you need is [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

[go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs) worked for me on a LG Spirit, with some of the same USB ids.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Ubuntu and MTP or PTP are the only available options then AirDroid is the best thing since sliced bread.