# How to mount an Android Jelly Bean phone if there's no option?

Tags: usb, android, smartphone, mtp

I can't mount the LG Optimus P700 (running the Android Jelly Bean OEM image) on my Ubuntu 12.10.

Other phones always have a selectable "Mass Storage" menu, but this one has no menu option for it when being connected to USB.

You can only select Media sync (MTP), USB tethering and "PC Software", which seems to be waiting for a custom software to answer when being selected.

If the device is connected, I can see it via lsusb, so the device is allowed in apparmor.

How can I manually mount the device?
Is it possible to mount such a device via mtp? How can I do that?

**Solutions:**

- AirDroid: AirDroid is an App that allows uploading files via HTTP (even inside an isolated LAN) to your phone and has many other features. It is available free in the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en
- Go-MTPFS: Go MTPFS is a FUSE filesystem using MTP (media transfer protocol) which is available on such phones while selecting "Connect to Media Suite" or similar. Installation instructions (also with a PPA): http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

Comment: If the phone(!) does not have a selectable `usb mass storage` option you can not. But google claims it does so maybe you have that option turned off?

Comment: Is there an entry in the developer settings or similar? Haven't found an option for it and I now think I'm a bit too stupid for this phone... but the usb popup menu differs from the other android devices.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Connecting Galaxy S3 (I747) to Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189591/connecting-galaxy-s3-i747-to-ubuntu-12-04/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install go-mtpfs from WebUpd8 repository following this guide:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

Then add `go-mtpfs-unity.desktop` the dash, connect your phone via usb and you have a quicklist to mount and dismount your android device.

Sorry for my bad English, I speak Spanish.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint! I actually had visited the project a while ago, but couldn't remember. It works like a charm and is a very good alternative to AirDroid.

Comment: Thanks in some way this also worked for my HOX on Ubuntu 12.10. This is soooooooooooooo bad that actually linux system as Android is has ANY problem in communication with another linux system as Ubuntu. In a real life it doesn't work at all without loosing hours to send few files to my phone!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with my Samsung Captivate Glide. In my opinion, not the perfect fix, but an option is an app "USB mode switch for SGS1 on CM" I got from the Play store. Worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a new, even smoother, method to achieve this using back-ported packages from Ubuntu 13.04. Please follow the guide from WebUpd8:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried for my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Samsung Galaxy S3. It is working. You need to install MTP file system on your ubuntu. then, try it.

installation of MTP file system.

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

then, unplug and plug your cell phone and restart your computer.