# What MTP program to use for HTC One X+

Tags: 12.10, android, mtp

Im running Xubuntu 12.10 and I'm trying to add files to my  HTC One X+ but the programs I've used (gMTP, Qlix and MTPFS using http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2055563) haven't worked at all as they all said they couldn't find any "raw devices"

Is there any other MTP Programs out there I can use that are more likely to work?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Connecting Galaxy S3 (I747) to Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189591/connecting-galaxy-s3-i747-to-ubuntu-12-04).

Comment: I'm having the same issue since the recent update to jelly bean. Basically, as I'm sure you've realised, mass storage has been disabled. Unfortunately the implementation of MTP is very poor. This means that file transfer is nigh on impossible. I contacted HTC and the only comment was that the device had never been intended to be used for file storage as such they will not support it. I can't directly answer your question as to whether there is an Ubuntu based MTP client that will work but when testing, do ensure that USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Install a FTP server on you android device and connect via FTP client from your PC. It's the only reliable way that I can connect after the Jellybean update (HTC One X, international version).

And HTC wonders why sales are down...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for transferring files, you can use remote control software, like [airdroid](http://www.airdroid.com/).

Answer (score 0):

On your phone try to enable USB debugging in Settings / Developer Options.

Comment: This does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine [HERE](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access)

Tested on:

- Ubuntu 13.04
- HTC One X Android 4.1.1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.