# What is the best way to get MTP working properly?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, mtp

Anyone have any news on the latest/best way to get Sony's proprietary MTP working properly on Ubuntu GNOME? Ubuntu GNOME Shell Remix 12.10 amd64. Sony Xperia U (no SD card support, only internal storage with MTP).

Comment: possible duplicate: [Connecting Galaxy S3 (I747) to Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/247046/23878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using with success the solution described by WebUpd8: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html.

Comment: I didn't know it but default Ubuntu with Unity already supports MTP out-of-the-box. Nice. :)