# Cannot add ppa for gvfs-mtp

Tags: mount, android, sudo, ppa

I am a total newbie concerning anything to do with Ubuntu/Linux.

I am running 12.04 on VM Player. I am trying to connect my HTC One (Android 4.3) to Ubuntu, and looking online has told me to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdelepl/gvfs-mtp
```

which will (through some magics that I have yet to understand), allow me to properly mount my phone as a usb device. But I keep getting:

```
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~langdelepl/+archive/gvfs-mtp) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

I've checked my Internet connection, and even gone to the URL, where it shows:

```
Object: <lp.systemhomes.WebServiceApplication object at 0x9026d90>, name: u'~langdelepl'
```

So there is definitely something there. I even tried doing the very involved version where you add the source through the Software Center, but it still didn't work. I've accessed a couple other PPA repositories through the terminal, so it just appears to be this one.

1. What the heck is causing the problem?
2. Why do I need MTP?
3. Is there any method other than MTP that would mount my phone (preferably without being *too* involved. keep in mind that I am an utter Linux newbie :p )

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Ps. I have made sure about 5 times now that the phone is connected to the VM via the Removable Devices menu. So it likely isn't that.

Comment: Are you sure it is `ppa:langdelepl/gvfs-mtp`? Can you provide the source?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189591/connecting-android-4ice-cream-sandwich-jelly-bean-kitkat-phone-to-ubuntu

Just one of the various sources I've found that say to do this.

Comment: Alright, so in the meantime I'm using AirDroid as a work-around. I can't compile directly to it, but I can save the .apks to it at least.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`

to add the repository  you want.

MTP is needed to access those device  which use Media Transfer Protocol to share data .

you can olso install `libmtp9`  by typing

`sudo apt-get install libmtp9`

Comment: I am typing  
  
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`

but I'm getting the errors.  
Is libmtp9 an alternative, or a prerequisite, or what?

Comment: after entering the libmtp9 command, it's saying  
`libmtp9 is already the newest version.  
libmtp9 set to manually installed  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: I dont know why `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp` giving you error if you have working internet connection as it is working fine on my computer.