# nautilus connect to server via ssh no longer present in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nautilus, 14.04

I just upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 and I see that the connect to another server via SSH is no longer part of the nautilus environment.  Can anyone direct me how to re-enable this feature.

thanks,
Wayne

Comment: `ssh://user@ip` doesn't work?

Comment: The above comment, Jo-Erlend Schinstad's answer and user275419's answer below is correct. You should, therefore, mark pick one as the correct one to save people like me having to look for the correct answer.

Comment: please mark your question answered. Mark the answer accepted, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 33):

It is still there in "Files > Connect to ..."

Enter `sftp://user@address/folder/` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I connected my raspberrypi this url: sftp://pi@192.168.1.5/home/

Answer (score 10):

open terminal

```
ctrl + Alt + T
```

type:

```
nautilus-connect-server
```

[image: Connect to server]

Enter your ssh ip address:

```
ssh://youripaddress
```

Enter your username and password:

[image: login]

You are done:
after successful login, you will see like this:

[image: server folder]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Perfect!! This does work flawlessly!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04: `nautilus-connect-server` gives `command not found`

Answer (score 7):

#### The problem

When trying to access a remote filesystem via `sftp` in `nautilus` (enter ^L to access the location bar, entered `sftp://user@host/export/dumps/client/user/` as uri, the current working directory gets prepended: `/home/user/sftp:/user@host/..`  and echoed in the error message(`/home/user` being the current working directory):

```
**Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.**
Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/user/sftp:/user@host/...': No such file or directory.
```

#### Short Answer

At least on my system, it seems that `sshfs` was not installed during the upgrade to 14.04.
Check if it is installed:

```
apt-cache policy sshfs
```

For me, installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

fixed the problem. (You need to restart the entire gnome desktop for this to become effective, so you may just as well reboot after installing it if you're on a desktop system without concerns about downtimes and server functionality)

The menu point for accessing a remote server (which used to be in the `File` menu) is now visible in the left pane under **Network - Connect to Server**. It is also possible to enter a URI (`sftp://user@server/path`) into the location bar that gets displayed when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

#### Long Answer

I've been battling this problem from another angle (see [deja-dup ssh method doesn't work - writes locally instead][1]), and finding the reason for the mysterious misbehaviour took me into the depths of

- gvfs
- sshfs
- fuse

#### Debugging process:

**trying to mount via gvfs:**

```
% gvfs-mount sftp://user@server/export/dumps/client/home/user
Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount
```

*If the user is not the one running the current desktop*, `gvfs-mount` needs to be prepended with `dbus-launch`:

```
dbus-launch gvfs-mount sftp://user@server/export/dumps/client/home/user
```

to be able to mount the remote directory. However, this doesn't seem permanent, so we're containing all our gvfs related stuff within one shell:

```
dbus-launch bash
gvfs-mount sftp://user@server/export/dumps/client/home/user
calibre@magrathea:~$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): ST320LT020-9YG142
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Volume(0): 5,4 GB Volume
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Volume(1): Nexus7
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Mount(0): user on server -> sftp://user@server/
  Type: GDaemonMount
nautilus &
```

Looks like `gvfs` mounted the remote home directory of `user` instead of the requested absolute path. Same if `/export` gets an additional `/` preprended. Within the `nautilus` that got called in the last line, an URI pointing to the desired absolute path can be entered and mounted once the underlying problem is solved.

**trying to mount via sshfs:**

#### Additional dependencies (incomplete):

- The user needs to be a member of the `fuse` group. Test with: `grep <username> /etc/group`, if he's missing: `sudo usermod -a -G fuse <user>`. With a passwordless group, the user needs to logout/re-login for this change to take effect.
- `gvfs-backend` needs to be installed

(to be continued)

[1]: [deja-dup ssh method doesn't work - writes locally instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459679/deja-dup-ssh-method-doesnt-work-writes-locally-instead). Check with `apt-cache policy gvfs-backend`

Answer (score 4):

You can also enter:
ssh://IP address

For example:
ssh://192.168.1.4

The resulting dialogue box will ask for user name and password on the machine you are trying to connect to and give you options about how to remember the user name and password.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of the Gnome file manager Nautilus (> Ubuntu 16.04), this feature has moved to a new location:

- Open the file manager
- Click *Other Locations*
- At the bottom of the window you will see a connection dialog

Clicking the querstion mark will give examples on how to enter the server and what protocols are supported.

[image: nautilus screenshot]

Comment: Works, but I hate this! They ruined with our loved Nautilus! Backing to use Nemo (`apt-get install nemo`) on Ubuntu Bionic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Nemo. Start by installing the dependencies-free version (open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

Launch Nemo and from the *File* menu select *Connect to Server*, this menu has the SSH option in *server type*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

Enter your ssh ip address:

sftp://youripaddress

*not* ssh://youripaddress

Comment: As i remember, when you suply a ssh:// protocol handler it asumes that you have typed sftp. Did u even try before answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **gvfs-backends** package, first.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep gvfs-backends
ii  gvfs-backends
```

If it`s not exist, please install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```