# Connect to server not recognizing sftp

Tags: 14.04, sftp

I am looking to try and sftp to my server using Ubuntu's "Files" window. From what I read I should be able to click "Connect to Server" and put in my address: sftp://user@ip/

The problem though is when I put that in, as soon as I hit the colon after sftp I get the following error just below in gray which does not go away even after I finish typing:

```
This file server type is not recognized
```

The connect button stays grayed out not letting me even try to connect.

I have tried pressing ctrl + l and putting in my location there, but it says:

```
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "ip(sftp)": The specified location is not supported.
```

Is there something I have to do to turn on sftp?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

Comment: What version of Nautilus are you using, and what happens when you try `ssh`?

Comment: ssh and ftp return the same messages. I suppose it's not nautilus as I tried "nautilus --version" It is whatever came with the default installation of ubuntu. Then I clicked "Files" on the left and then "Connect to Server"

Comment: `sftp` works on Nautilus 3.8.4 (I use it regularly due to laziness) - is SSH installed, and can you access it from the command line ssh? You can check the version by finding a 'About' item in a help/global menu ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xihA2.png))

Comment: From reading, it seems that nautilus is pre-installed as the main file browser for Ubuntu 14.04. However I am not sure how to get the version because nautilus --version says nautilus is not installed.

Comment: Yes, I can access ssh through terminal, to the same server I am trying to access in the file browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I was missing gvfs. I installed it and now I have access to ssh:// and sftp://

Answer (score 0):

If a list of options is provided for type of server to connect to, use the `ssh` option if it's available.  Since before 10.04, it's always been listed as "SSH" instead of "SFTP".

In 14.04 where it asks for the `prefix://address/` style of things, `sftp` is unrecognized.  It uses `ssh://` instead.  So, accordingly, `sftp://1.2.3.4/` becomes `ssh://1.2.3.4/`.

Comment: ssh, sftp, and ftp return the same result

Comment: @Samir Don't put the prefix in the address.  So `sftp://1.2.3.4/` becomes `1.2.3.4`.  It auto-adds the corresponding prefix.

Comment: Now it is not giving the first error, but it still grays out the connect button not allowing me to connect to an IP. When I use the ctrl+l method I get the same error as before.

Comment: Did you put all the other options in such as username and password?  You have to provide those as well.  If you want, take a screenshot of what you're doing and share it (obfuscating the private information) as well, it might help me to understand what you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry, this is a new install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I am still new to how it works. When I click "Connect to Server" I get one input box to put in the "Server Address" There are no other options

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/JY1m3Q6

Comment: @Samir I updated my response now that I got my hands on my 14.04 Ubuntu system (it was down until I could replace the system fan). It uses `ssh://` instead of `sftp://`.  Try that.

Comment: I appreciate the time you are taking to help, but ssh:// sftp:// and ftp:// are not working. Should I try to manually install nautilus instead of relying on the version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: No the version in 14.04 works fine.  Note the string format to use is `ssh://USER@address:PORT` - make sure you are using that string format

Comment: gvfs apparently was not installed, so it was not allowing ssh:// sftp:// and ftp://

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem.
According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/545501/1191133), I installed `gvfs`, but that's not enough; the problem remains.
I then installed `sshfs` and `gvfs-backends` according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/459989/1191133) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/543952/1191133) answers, and then problem solved.