# Open folder GUI in remote machine

Tags: ssh, nautilus, remote

I have ssh connection with a remote machine (`ssh username@server`). But now I want to open a certain folder `path/to/folder` in a GUI environment. The following I've tried while being in `username@server:/path/to/folder`:
Input:

```
nautilus .
```

Output:

```
The program 'nautilus' is currently not installed.
To run 'nautilus' please ask your administrator to install the package 'nautilus'
```

So `nautilus` is not installed on the remote machine, but it is on my local machine.

I've tried `xdg-open` aswell. It does work, but that is not really what I want. I want the same interface while browsing my local machine (so basically nautilus).

Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks in advance, if there is anything unclear, please ask!

*PS. I do not have the rights to install anything on the remote machine.*

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/456669/nautilus-connect-to-server-via-ssh-no-longer-present-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Basically you use 'Connect to Server' in your *local* nautilus to connect to the remote system using sftp/scp (separate from your ssh terminal session)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the suggestion. I found a similar solution but with the terminal. I've included your suggestion to the answer as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two methods worked for me:

1. **Solution of steeldriver (see the comment under the question):**
   'Connect to Server' in *local* nautilus to connect to the remote system
2. **Similar solution but in the terminal:**
   Open the terminal (`Alt+Ctrl+T`) locally and run: `nautilus sftp://username@server:/path/to/folder` or even better `nohup nautilus sftp://username@server:/path/to/folder &` to keep it running even when the terminal is closed.

Comment: Remember to select this as the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `sshfs` protocol. This allows you to mount any remote file system that you have permissions to over the SSH protocol easily.

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
mkdir ~/Remote
sshfs user@remotehost:/path/to/remote/folder ~/Remote
```

It will ask you for your SSH credentials if you aren't set-up with public-key authentication. Then you can open it up in your local Nautilus or any other file manager, as well as work with the files in the terminal. Also note that the `mkdir` line is only needed the first time you mount. After the first time mounting, all you need to do is:

```
sshfs user@remotehost:/path/to/remote/folder ~/Remote
```

When you are done:

```
sudo umount /home/<USER>/Remote
```

While it is mounted, you will have the same permissions as whichever user you connected through SSH as. So, if you mount a folder where your SSH user only has read access, you will only have read access.